# org.gradle.api.internal.LocationAwareException from gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a gradle build error from the following gradle file. But I am clueless why it failed.
Please advise.

Thanks,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.RC4")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' <== This is line 14

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

@localhost hello]$ gradle
org.gradle.api.internal.LocationAwareException: Build file '/home/xxx/dev/src/main/java/hello/build.gradle' line: 14
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hello'.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:85)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:20)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hello'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:462)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:74)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:438)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:433)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/gradle/api/Task;
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.SpringBootPlugin.addRepackageTask(SpringBootPlugin.java:94)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.SpringBootPlugin.applyRepackage(SpringBootPlugin.java:60)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.SpringBootPlugin.apply(SpringBootPlugin.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.SpringBootPlugin.apply(SpringBootPlugin.java:1)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.apply(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject.java:840)
```

Comment: Could you try with gradle 1.9?

Comment: Actually it works for me with gradle 1.11, so maybe your gradle environment is messed up somehow? Try with a fresh wrapper or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That method `create(String,Class<?>)` was introduced in [Gradle 1.6](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/61782c34109417a73e009cadaa0546712131fb2c), so I suspect you have a mouldy Gradle wrapper (or some other messed up Gradle environment). The configuration says the wrapper generated is 1.11, but I think maybe you are running with an older version?

Comment: you get this in Eclipse/STS all the time, to fix you need to add the wrapper task, remove the bit causing the issue (in this case the spring boot plugin), run gradle wrapper, and then re-apply the spring boot plugin. This will get the wrapper running the correct gradle version

Comment: I had this error in Ubuntu 14.04 with Gradle 1.4. After upgrading to Gradle 2.2.1 with the instructions from [wesley tanaka](http://wtanaka.com/node/8079) I was able to successfully build my project.